# JAXRS 2.1: ServletContext cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, microprofile

I've added this microprofile dependency:

```
compile("org.eclipse.microprofile:microprofile:2.1")
```

So inside `microprofile:2.1` is contained `JAX-RS 2.1`.

Into my code, I'm trying to use this code:

```
@PreMatching
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class TLSClientCertificateFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ServletContext request;

}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to inject current `ServletContext`, but compiler is telling me that

> ServletContext cannot be resolved to a type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to the [org.eclipse.microprofile:microprofile:2.1 pom](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.microprofile/microprofile/2.1/pom), there is no any declared dependency to the `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api`. We have to define it at our project pom as the following example

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${my.servlet.api.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note the `${my.servlet.api.version}` is depended on our target container which may be a `4.0`.

Comment: I solved that using `providedCompile("javax:javaee-api:8.0")`. Which is the difference between `javax.servlet-api`.
Another question comes me up is why microprofile compliance servers (liberty, payara...) are javaee8 compliance as well? I mean, I thought these servers only provided a set of javaee... not all...

Comment: AFAIU, the microprofile FAQ said that "The MicroProfile is a baseline platform definition that optimizes Enterprise Java for a microservices architecture and delivers application portability across multiple MicroProfile runtimes". These may be  about the application/service point-of-view, and may be not about those servers. (https://microprofile.io/faq/)